# Twice contracted Bianchi identity from diffeomorphism invariance

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity, lie-derivative, diffeomorphism

I've been reading Straumann's book "General Relativity & Relativistic Astrophysics". In it, he claims that the twice contracted Bianchi identity: $$\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}=0$$ (where $G^{\mu\nu}=R^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R$) is a consequence of the diffeomorphism (diff) invariance of the Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action. Now, I can show (I think) that the EH action is diff invariant, by considering a infinitesimal diff, generated by a vector field $X$: $$\delta_{X}S_{EH}=\phi^{\ast}S_{EH}-S_{EH}=\int_{M}\mathcal{L}_{X}\left(d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}R\right)=\int_{M}\left[\mathcal{L}_{X}\left(d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\right)R +d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}_{X}\left(R\right)\right]\\ \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\;=\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\left[\nabla_{\mu}X^{\mu}R+X^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}R\right]=\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\,\nabla_{\mu}\left(X^{\mu}R\right)\\ =\int_{\partial M}d^{3}x\sqrt{h}\,n_{\mu}X^{\mu}R=0\;\;\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$ where $h_{ij}$ is the induced metric on the boundary $\partial M$ of the manifold $M$, with $n^{\mu}$ the normal vector to the boundary. The last equality follows upon the assumption that $X^{\mu}$ has compact support in $M$.

However, I'm unsure how one uses this fact to derive the (twice-contracted) Bianchi identity?

Straumann simply writes: $$\delta S=\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{EH}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\right)\delta g^{\mu\nu}=\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\,G_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}=-\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\,G^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$$ and notes that for an infinitesimal diff (generated by some vector field $X$), $\delta g_{\mu\nu}=2\nabla_{(\mu}X_{\nu)}$, such that $$\delta_{X} S=-2\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\,G^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}X_{\nu}=2\int_{M}d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\,X_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}=0$$ and so, since $X^{\nu}$ is arbitrary, it must be that $\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}=0$.

What confuses me about this, is that one neglects the effect of the Lie derivative on $d^{4}x$ in this case (in the proof that the EH action is diff invariant, it was taken into account). Is the point that an infinitesimal diff is carried out in the *same* coordinate chart, and so $d^{4}x$ doesn't change in this case?